# How do I get photos into social media

Tags: software-installation

I have uploaded pictures from my camera to my computer running Ubuntu but when I go to upload them to social media I can not find them. When I click on picture folder just blank numbered folders open.

Comment: Where is the camera mounted? Did you actually copy those files to your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I plugged camera into tower and pictures transferred into a photo app that Ubuntu uses on my computer but outside of when you first import them pictures can't be found or seen

Answer (score 1):

The numbered folders represent dates.  The pictures should be sorted into the folders by the date they were taken.  Keep opening folders until you find your pictures.  If all the folders are empty, then something may have gone wrong when you imported the pictures into Shotwell.  If you run Shotwell you should see your pictures if they imported correctly; you should be able to right-click on one of the pictures in Shotwell and click Properties to see exactly where it is stored.  Good luck!